# Only part of a program executing

Tags: c#, .net, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I'm following this tutorial https://mva.microsoft.com/en-us/training-courses/c-fundamentals-for-absolute-beginners-16169?l=83b9cRQIC_9706218949
and I can't get the program working although I have copied the exact code as in the tutorial.

I have Ubuntu 16.04 so I'm using Visual Studio Code. And I have .NET SDK version 2.1.403.

Here's the code for my program:

```
using System;

   namespace Decision
   {
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Miina's Big Giveaway");
            Console.Write("Choose a door: 1, 2 or 3 ");
            string userValue = Console.ReadLine();

            if (userValue == "1")
            {
                string message = "You won a new car!";
                Console.WriteLine(message);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the program isn't writing the line "Choose a door...". Only when I stop the execution of the program, the line "Choose a door ..." appears in the debug terminal.

And if I try typing "1" while the program is still running nothing happens although it should go through the commands in the if statement. I can't figure out where's the problem.

**Update on the debugging**
When I'm debugging a light bulb appears next to the Console.Write -line. I'm not sure what that means.
[Picture of the debugging result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXmP1.png)
 **Update**
The program is working correctly when I run it through the terminal. So I guess I have to use the terminal with the Visual Studio Code. But it would be nice to use debugger, so if anyone knows how I could get it to work, let me know.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?  Stepping through the code line by line to see what it's actually doing?

Comment: Just to make sure but the line `Miina's Big Giveaway` is displaying correctly?

Comment: You might be running an older version of the code?  Do a rebuild.

Comment: How are you running your program? Are you sure you are running the correct file?

Comment: Did you press the Enter key after typing "1"?

Comment: I assume you're using Mono? Are you sure you configured it correctly?

Comment: @MetaColon - He said he's using SDK 2.1.403, that's .net core, not mono.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.openstandardoutput?view=netcore-2.0 might be of some use (just a guess on my part), try `Console.OpenStandardOutput(0)` though I don't know if this is supported on linux (even though it's in core 2.0 ...).

Comment: I've tried debugging, the program just stops on the Console.Write -line.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that `Console.Write` isn't being flushed (stdout on Linux is unbuffered, and is only flushed on a line ending).

Try `Console.Out.Flush()` as a work-around. It's not pretty, though.

Comment: What you mean by flushed?

Comment: I changed Console.Write() to Console.Out.Flush() and got an error "No overload for method 'Flush' takes 1 arguments".

Comment: The error suggests that you're passing an argument to `Flush()`; it doesn't take any...